# some thing wrong in codeigniter,is ture?

Tags: php, codeigniter

testing in windows,php5.5 and ci 3.1.8
I create a test.php like this:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['admin']="1";
    $str =array("_SESSION"=>array("isadmin"=>"admin","user"=>"user1"));
    extract($str);
    print_r($_SESSION);
```

run it,Return result:
Array ( [isadmin] => admin [user] => user1 )

delect the session file,and create a Welcome.php in ci,like that:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

/**
 * Index Page for this controller.
 *
 * Maps to the following URL
 *         http://example.com/index.php/welcome
 *    - or -
 *         http://example.com/index.php/welcome/index
 *    - or -
 * Since this controller is set as the default controller in
 * config/routes.php, it's displayed at http://example.com/
 *
 * So any other public methods not prefixed with an underscore will
 * map to /index.php/welcome/<method_name>
 * @see https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html
 */
public function index()
{
    $this->load->view('welcome_message');
}
public function test()
{
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['admin']="1";
    $str =array("_SESSION"=>array("isadmin"=>"admin","user"=>"user1"));
    extract($str);
    print_r($_SESSION);
}

}
```

and run it in http://localhost/index.php/welcome/test
Return result:

Array ( [admin] => 1 )

The result of the operation is not the same. some thing wrong?

Comment: How to use codeigniter sessions https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html and setup https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#session-preferences

Comment: It's better to use CI's session library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

extract :Import variables from an array into the **current** symbol table.

just **current** symbol table

see http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php